# Как объединить запрос через Join в SQL

Tags: sql

Как объединить три запроса в один? Беру по данные из трех таблиц и хочу вывести в 4-рой таблице имена по айдишникам..

```
SELECT FIO as Преподаватель FROM prepodavateli 
    JOIN predmet_has_groups on Prepodavateli_idprepodavateli = idprepodavateli

SELECT NaimenovaniePredmeta as предмет FROM predmet 
    JOIN predmet_has_groups on predmet_idPredmet = idPredmet

SELECT Name as группа FROM groupps 
    JOIN predmet_has_groups on Groups_idGroups = idGroups
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вы можете написать несколько `JOIN` к одному основному `SELECT`, каждый со своим условием `ON`

Comment: Использовать таблицу `predmet_has_groups` как базовую. и JOIN к ней всех трёх остальных таблиц.